# Como ver si registro tipo boolean MySQL es NULL

Tags: php, mysql, booleano

Tengo una tabla de MySQL y uno de los campos es de tipo `Boolean`, entonces varios registros con valor 1, 0 y algunos en NULL.
En PHP recorro la tabla y con un `switch` ejecuto codigo cuando es 1 y cuando es 0, pero cuando es `NULL` lo toma como si fuera 0 o false. La pregunta es ¿como detecto cuando es `NULL`?

Intenté eso y sigue tomandolo como false.

```
switch ($cumple) {
  case 1:
     echo "   cumple<BR>";
     break;
  case 0:
     echo "   no cumple<BR>";
     break;
  case NULL:
     echo "   null<BR>";
     break; 
}
```

[image: sq]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## El problema

Es que **[`switch ... case`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php)** se vale de [*comparaciones flexibles*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose), en las cuales:

- `NULL` es igual a `FALSE`
- `NULL` es igual a `0` (número)

(Ver los recuadros en rojo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Una solución

En las comparaciones flexibles, `-1` no es igual a `NULL` (ver recuadro verde ^). Entonces, podemos hacer una verificación de `$cumple` y cambiarla a `-1` cuando sea `null`. De este modo solventaremos el problema.

Aquí, mediante un ternario, verificamos si `$cumple` es null y le asignamos `-1` en ese caso, de lo contrario guardará su valor.

```
#Evaluamos tanto null como "null" en caso de que el valor sea casteado a string
$cumple = ($cumple===NULL || strtolower($cumple)==="null") ? -1 : $cumple;
```

A partir de ahí, el `switch` va a funcionar de la forma esperada.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba la funcion `is_null()` de php

```js
switch ($cumple) {
  case 1:
     echo "   cumple<BR>";
     break;
  case 0:
     echo "   no cumple<BR>";
     break;
  case is_null($cumple):
     echo "   null<BR>";
     break; 
}
```

EDIT: Hay varias formas de hacerlo, como por ejemplo igualarlo a `$variable == undefined` o con `$variable === NULL`, depende del caso. A las malas, puedes hacer un `var_dump($variable)` para ver que te está devolviendo en cualquier caso.

Y a las muy malas, para tu caso concreto, puedes dejarlo en el `default`:

```js
switch ($cumple) {
  case 1:
     echo "   cumple<BR>";
     break;
  case 0:
     echo "   no cumple<BR>";
     break;
  default:
     echo "   null<BR>";
     break; 
}
```

Comment: ya lo habia intentado y no funciona, de hecho, si pongo el  case is_null arriba del case 0, toma los falses como null, pero gracias.

Comment: Editado, que es lo que te muestra var_dump()?

Comment: me devuelve NULL.

Comment: A ver, es un poco chapuza, pero a las muy malas, lo haces en el default del switch

Comment: Mira como lo dejé, al reves y bueno, funciona jaja.

Comment: te sugiero usar este modelo: `if(is_scalar($cumple){ ($cumple==1) ? hacer_si_true() : hacer_si_false(); }else{ hacer_si_null(); }` La primera validación te lleva a los casos importantes y sólo será cierta si efectivamente hay valor **no nulo** guardado.

Answer (score 3):

Podés probar así sino:

```
case (NULL===$cumple):
```

Recomiendo leer la documentación de mysql con php, ya que hay muchas formas de verificar si es null sin necesidad de un switch.

Comment: probé y tampoco, pero gracias.  pd: Utilizo switch ya que necesito hacer algo diferente en cada caso.

Comment: finalmente use lo que me dijiste pero al reves, como se ve en la nueva imagen que subí y funcionó... sigo sin entender por que.

Comment: Voy a corregir la respuesta lo pondré al revés, y si se solucionó agradecería le des click a solucionado en la respuesta asi ayudamos a futuras personas con éste errror.